# Time series clustering: diss.AR.MAH, p-value interpretation problem

Tags: r, time-series, p-value, arima

I'm trying to learn to use `tsclust` package, namely `diss.AR.MAH`. However, I'm having an annoying problem. `diss.AR.MAH` is supposed to test two series, say X and Y, if they come from the same ARMA model. It gives two outputs: *statistic* and *p-value*.

My problem is that, when I generate two vectors from the same ARIMA models, P-value is large, say, 0.93. However, when I generate a vector from normal distribution, when I test for p-values, p-value is again large, with 0.47. What am I missing, I guess, when comparing against normal random variates, I shoul have had a low p-value. I m clearly missing something but I don'n know what. Here is my sample code:

```
x <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(0.4,-0.1)), n =100, n.start=100)
y <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(0.4,-0.1)), n =100, n.start=100)
diss.AR.MAH(x, y)
```

with output:
$statistic          [,1]
[1,] 0.1429621

$p_value
          [,1]
[1,] 0.9310139

and when I do it for,

```
x <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(0.4,-0.1)), n =100, n.start=100)
y <- rnorm(100,10)
diss.AR.MAH(x, y)
```

with the ouutput:

$statistic
          [,1]
[1,] 0.4993418

$p_value
          [,1]
[1,] 0.479789